# get location if the location is turned off from settings

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I need to get lat/lng from the android device but the restriction is that my device location is turned off from settings and users requirement is not to turn on the location.

so is it possible to get lat/lng from device?

Comment: you can get last location, but that's not perfect location. So, need to on location service if, want to use location in application.

For more info https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: last location is available if the location is enabled from settings, if don't then you are not able to get last location.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use LocationManager.

Read the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html).

Edit:- Sorry, There is no way as of my knowledge. Getting the location when user doesn't want to, is not possible by ethical means.

Comment: Location manager is used if the location services are turned on.

Answer (score 0):

call this Intent when location is off

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),110);
```

OR call this method when you want to get user location.

```
public boolean isLocationEnable() {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    if (locationManager == null)
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    try {
        gps_enabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    boolean network_enabled = false;
    try {
        network_enabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Activate Location");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Setting",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                            int paramInt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        startActivityForResult(
                                new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                                110);
                    }
                });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                            int paramInt) {
                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```